# How this piece of code can be improved or optimized

Tags: javascript, typescript, logic

How this code can be improved or optimized. Though it gives the required result. I want to write it with a better approach.

I am fetching data from www.contentful.com and then filtring it to get the localization with their keys. Note we have to use .reduce() function it is a requirement

```
   import * as fs from 'fs';
   const client = createClient();
   interface IEntry {
     id: string;
     text: string;
   }
   interface IEntries {
     [key: string]: { [key: string]: string };
   }

   export async function getLocalization() {
     const entries = await client.getEntries<IEntry>({
       skip: 0,
       limit: 100,
       locale: '*',
       content_type: 'translation',
     });

     let enEntries: IEntries = entries.items
       .map((e: any) => e.fields)
       .reduce(
         (ret, entry) => ({
           ...ret,
           [entry.id.fi]: entry.text.en,
         }),
       {},
       );

     let fiEntries: IEntries = entries.items
       .map((e: any) => e.fields)
       .reduce(
         (ret, entry) => ({
           ...ret,
           [entry.id.fi]: entry.text.fi,
         }),
         {},
          );

  let svEntries: IEntries = entries.items
    .map((e: any) => e.fields)
    .reduce(
      (ret, entry) => ({
        ...ret,
        [entry.id.fi]: entry.text.sv,
      }),
      {},
    );

  const translations = {
    ['en']: { ...enEntries },
    ['fi']: { ...fiEntries },
    ['sv']: { ...svEntries },
  };

  const dir = './data';
  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
  }
  fs.writeFileSync('data/translations.json', JSON.stringify(translations));
  return true;
}
getLocalization();

Output can be found on this link (actual values have been removed): https://imgur.com/k3rzxWx
```

Comment: This looks like it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The sample output JSON can be found out at the following link: https://imgur.com/k3rzxWx

Comment: Ohhh i never knew there is such thing :D thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the following approach will be best in this case.

```
import { IFields, ITranslation } from './localization.types';
import * as fs from 'fs';
const client = createClient();

const en: ITranslation = {};
const fi: ITranslation = {};
const sv: ITranslation = {};

export async function getLocalization() {
  const entries = await client.getEntries<IFields>({
    skip: 0,
    limit: 100,
    locale: '*',
    content_type: 'translation',
  });
  const localizations = entries.items
    .map(e => e.fields)
    .reduce(
      (ret, entry) => {
        ret.en[entry.id.fi] = entry.text.en === undefined ? 'no_value_found' : entry.text.en;
        ret.fi[entry.id.fi] = entry.text.fi === undefined ? 'no_value_found' : entry.text.fi;
        ret.sv[entry.id.fi] = entry.text.sv === undefined ? 'no_value_found' : entry.text.sv;
        return ret;
      },
      { en, fi, sv },
    );
  const dir = './data';
  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
  }
  fs.writeFileSync('data/translations.json', JSON.stringify(localizations));
  return true;
}
getLocalization();
```

And following are the types

```
export interface IId {
  fi: string;
}

export interface IText {
  en: string;
  fi: string;
  sv: string;
}

export interface IFields {
  id: IId;
  text: IText;
}

export interface ITranslation {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks quite fine, you can however add a helper to save the repetition:

```
 // Can be replaced with Object.fromEntries(values.map(getDescriptor)) soon
 function mapOf<E, V>(values: Array<E>, getDescriptor: (entry: E) => [string, V]): { [key: string]: V } {
   const result = {};
   for(const entry of values) {
     const [key, value] = getDescriptor(entry);
     result[key] = value;
   }
   return result;
 }


 const translations = {
   en: mapOf(entries.items, it => ([it.fields.id.fi, it.fields.text.en])),
   fi: mapOf(entries.items, it => ([it.fields.id.fi, it.fields.text.fi])),
   sv: mapOf(entries.items, it => ([it.fields.id.fi, it.fields.text.sv])),
 };
```

Or as another approach you could fill your translations object automatically when iterating the entries:

```
  const translations = { en: {}, fi: {}, sv: {}, };

  for(const it of entries.items) {
     const key = it.fields.id.fi, values = it.fields.text;
     for(const language in values) {  
       if(!translations[language]) continue;
       translations[language][key] = values[language];
     }
  }
```

Comment: `const localizations = entries.items
    /* tslint:disable */
    .map((e: any) => e.fields)
    .reduce(
      (ret, entry) => {
        ret.en[entry.id.fi] = entry.text.en === undefined ? 'no_value_found' : entry.text.en;
        ret.fi[entry.id.fi] = entry.text.fi === undefined ? 'no_value_found' : entry.text.fi;
        ret.sv[entry.id.fi] = entry.text.sv === undefined ? 'no_value_found' : entry.text.sv;
        return ret;
      },
      { en: {}, fi: {}, sv: {} },
    );`

Comment: @ jonas What do you think about this? and how can i get rid of this any do you have any idea

Comment: I personally don't like that reduce pattern, but thats personal preference. Your `IEntries` type doesnt really match the type you are using, you should make that type match the actual structure.

Comment: Yes you are right there was an issue with the types